# watchify : The term 'watchify' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried the following command

```
npm install react browserify watchify 6to5ify --save-dev
```

and then i tried this

```
 watchify -t 6to5ify ./app.jsx ./bundle.js -v
```

but it complains that

```
watchify : The term 'watchify' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ watchify -t 6to5ify ./app.jsx ./bundle.js -v
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (watchify:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried to install watchify again using:

```
npm install watchify
```

and i am sure it is installed 
[image]

but i have still the same problem.

Comment: This error means `watchify` cannot be found in the PATH. Either install it globally (recommended for many command-line tools, and where it is found in the global node bin folder, already in the PATH) or run it from where it is installed in the local node_modules (eg. `node_modules/.bin/watchify` or the variant it is).

Comment: do you mean, i have to navigate inside node_module?

Comment: He meant that you should add node_modules/.bin to your PATH variable.
btw, windows is not the best way to use web dev tools. Vagrant is a way to go on a windows machines.

Comment: If you look at [the docs](https://github.com/substack/watchify#install) it's `npm install -g watchify`.